# Authenticate to SQL Server through PowerShell with MFA (Active Directory Interactive)

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-sql-database, always-encrypted

I am trying to set up a PowerShell script to enable Always Encrypted on our Azure SQL Server databases. I am following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-using-powershell?view=sql-server-ver15), which offers the following sample code:

```
# Import the SqlServer module
Import-Module "SqlServer"  

# Connect to your database
# Set the valid server name, database name and authentication keywords in the connection string
$serverName = "<Azure SQL server name>.database.windows.net"
$databaseName = "<database name>"
$connStr = "Server = " + $serverName + "; Database = " + $databaseName + "; Authentication = Active Directory Integrated"
$database = Get-SqlDatabase -ConnectionString $connStr

# List column master keys for the specified database.
Get-SqlColumnMasterKey -InputObject $database
```

I run into problems however with getting the database connection to work. From what it seems the `Get-SqlDatabase` command from the SqlServer module that is used does not seem to support login through MFA. Our company have enforced this type of login, so I can't seem to find a way around this.

When running `Get-SqlDatabase -ConnectionString 'Server=myserver.database.windows.net; Database=myDB; Authentication=Active Directory Interactive;'` I receive the following error:

> Cannot find an authentication provider for 'ActiveDirectoryInteractive'.

Does SqlServer-module lack the ability to support MFA logins? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Get-SqlDatabase` Cmdlet uses the `System.Data.SqlClient` wherein as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) below values are supported in Authentication Keyword.

Valid values are:

- Active Directory Integrated
- Active Directory Password
- Sql Password

**Active Directory Integrated** :To use This authentication mode can be, you need to federate the on-premise Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) with Azure Active Directory in the cloud

**Active Directory Password**: `authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword` can be used to connect to an Azure SQL Database/Synapse Analytics using an Azure AD user name and password.

**Sql Password** :`Use authentication=SqlPassword` to connect to a SQL Server using userName/user and password properties.

If you want to Authenticate to Sql Server through PowerShell with MFA you need to use `Active Directory Interactive` in authentication keyword which is not supported by `system.data.sqlclient`

**Active Directory Interactive**:`authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive` can be used to connect to an Azure SQL Database/Synapse Analytics using an interactive authentication flow (multi-factor authentication)

Please note that the `System.Data.SqlClient` driver, and consequently the `Get-SqlDatabase cmdlet`, does not support the full range of Azure AD authentication methods. If none of the supported methods works in your environment, using SQL authentication may be the only option.

Comment: Alright, thanks! That was what I feared. So there seems to be no current way to use PowerShell to set up Always Encrypted that supports authentication through MFA?

Comment: Yes, currently it is not based on the documentation as mentioned above

Comment: I raised a documentation enhancement issue to stop anyone else having this issue. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/7028